# Is there a good way to iterate through the maximum values of a BST with heap-like properties?

Tags: data-structures, tree, binary-tree, binary-search-tree, heap

I am working with a tree of nodes organized as a sort of binary search tree for property 1 that maintains a max heap ordering for property 2, and I want to iterate through the maximum values for property 2.

My current solution involves making a copy of the tree, and then iteratively find a leaf, pop the current root, placing the leaf at the root of the tree, and down heaping that node to a suitable position, however this solutions seems overly complex and inefficient, so I was wondering whether there exists a simpler/faster way to achieve the same goal

[Example Tree](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tDfvv.png)

Comment: Can you explain how the max heap ordering for property 2 is maintained within a binary tree that's ordered on property 1?

Comment: @JimMischel The tree is a binary search tree with respect to property 1, which maintains the property that the root of each subtree is the maximum property 2 of the subtree. I also added an example tree if that helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is in general no efficient way to iterate over a max heap (or min heap) in sequential order.

For a max heap, we know that the largest item is at the root. The second largest will be one of the two children of the root. The third-largest could be a child of the root, or a grand-child of the root. And so on. The smallest item in a max heap can be any leaf node. Finding the xth item (by value) in a binary heap is an expensive operation.

The two most efficient ways to get the values of a binary heap in sequential order are:

1. Repeatedly do `removeMax` followed by re-adjusting the heap at each turn.
2. Make a copy of the heap and sort it.

Either way is O(n log n).